# Adding Product To Cart Leads To Infinite Loop

Tags: addtocart

I have an observer set up to listen for 'checkout_cart_product_update_after', 'checkout_cart_product_add_after', 'sales_quote_remove_item', and 'checkout_cart_update_items_after'.

The goal for my observer is to check to see if groups of SKUs have been added in a sufficient quantity to qualify for bonus and price reduction.  For example:

If there are 20 items from group X there would be Y bonus items added.  My problem is that the adding of the bonus items triggers "checkout_cart_product_add_after" and I'm getting an infinite loop.  Attached is the code:

```
<?php
class Test_ManageCart_Model_Observer
{
    private $_debug = true;
    private $_skus = array(
      array("1002S","1CYOS",18210,15510,1002)
    );
    private $_steps = array(
      array(50, 80, 100, 200, 300, 400)
    );
    private $_rates = array(
      array(56.92, 55.87, 54.79, 52.70, 49.85, 46.80, 39.60)
    );
    // we use our constructor/destructor just to make it easier to spot output in the     log file
    function __construct () {
      $this->log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    }
    function __destruct () {
      $this->log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    }
    public function manageCart($observer)
    {
      $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
      // variable to keep track of counts for various sku groupings we've set in     $_sku
      $counts = array();
      foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        // reset prices
    $this->resetRate($item);
        // loop through all our sku rules to see if this one matches any
        foreach ($this->_skus as $index=>$skus) {
          // if so, add to the cumulative count
          if (in_array($item->getSku(), $skus)) {
            $counts[$index] += $item->getQty();
          }
        }
      }
      $this->log(print_r($counts, true));
      // loop through thresholds to see if any have been met
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->_skus); $i++) {
        // base threshold is used to keep track of the last one we passed, we have to     loop through
        // to make sure we're acknowledging the highest one
        $baseThreshold = -1;
        foreach ($this->_steps[$i] as $index=>$step) {
          if ($counts[$i] >= $step) {
            $baseThreshold = $index;
          }
        }
        // if we've met a threshold, loop through the products again and give the
        // necessary discount
        if ($baseThreshold != -1) {
          foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if (in_array($item->getSku(), $this->_skus[$i])) {
              $this->setRate($item, $this->_rates[$i][$baseThreshold]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    public function resetRate($item) {
      $item->setCustomPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());
      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(false);
    }
    public function setRate($item, $price) {
      $item->setCustomPrice($price);
      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
    public function log($string) {
      if ($this->_debug) {
        Mage::log($string);
      }
    }
}
```

I feel like the solution lies somewhere in setting a meta value for the cart, but so far I haven't found a good way to deal with this.  Is there a built in Magento way of keeping track of the fact that I've already added the items?

Comment: Is there are reason to use a 2d array?

Comment: Yes, eventually there will be more groups of SKUs.  Right now I'm just using one, but the idea is that I can define different groups with different steps, rates, and bonuses.

Comment: does the infinite loop go away after you remove the 2nd dispatch event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was tied with this: [Get SKU Of Item Removed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46511/get-sku-of-item-removed/)

As alluded to in the question, I was adding a product from the observer (that was listening for products being added to the cart) based off certain conditions.  The solution was to make sure that my added products had "BONUS_" in the SKU and not act on bonuses that were added.