# Get SKU Of Item Removed

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

In my extension's config.xml I'm observing the sales_quote_remove_item event.  I'd like to get the SKU of the item that was removed from the cart.

I've the steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255083/magento-how-to-check-if-a-product-has-already-been-removed-from-the-cart to no avail.  var_dump() on the $observer object spits out too much info to be intelligible.

I have a custom extension that adds bonus products depending on certain groups.  I'd like for it to continue listening on sales_quote_remove_item but to ignore any of the bonus SKUs themselves.

Comment: Can you post your code? It is a little hard answering when you can't see what you have already have done.

Comment: the $product variable, have you tried var_dump($product->getData())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to use getEvent().  The following worked:

```
public function manageCart($observer) {

  $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

  // do nothing if we're adding or removing BONUS
  if ($product) {
          if (strpos($product->getSku(), "BONUS") !== false) {
            $this->log("getProduct() skipping BONUS");
            return; // exit observer
          }
  } else {
        /* other logic here */

....
```